# Angular 2 - Using "multi" provider to override Http

Tags: angular, angular2-http, angular2-providers

I want to override `Http` with a custom class, say `HttpClient` to do some operations before a request and after a response, however I don't want to have to remember to import that class instead of the platform http class.

I've been experimenting with doing this via the 'multi' providers, but I can't quite make it click.

Here's my override class:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {
  private http: Http;

  constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    doSomethingToHeader(headers);
    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }
}
```

And here's my main.ts

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  provide(HTTP_PROVIDERS, {useExisting: HTTP_PROVIDERS, multi: true}),
  provide(HTTP_PROVIDERS, {useClass: HttpClient, multi: true})
]);
```

But when I try to call http.get() in my app, I get

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Http!
```

Any ideas? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I found this [blog post](https://www.illucit.com/blog/2016/03/angular2-http-authentication-interceptor/).  It pretty much describes what Gunter describes below. I'm accepting his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multi: true` only works when the provider is designed to be a `multi` provider like `PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES`. `HTTP_PROVIDERS` are not `multi` providers, it's just a collection of individual providers.

What you can do is

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, {provide: Http, useClass: HttpClient}])
```

**results in cycles** (see comments)

This should work:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS, 
  {
    provide: Http, 
    useFactory: (backend, defaultOptions) => new HttpClient(new Http(backend, defaultOptions)),
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  }
])
```

The important part is that your custom provider that overrides the provider defined in `HTTP_PROVIDERS` comes **after** the one you want to override. Therefore it's important that `HTTP_PROVIDERS` comes before `{provide: Http, ...}`

With `multi: true` you don't override a provider but instead add another item to a provider that provides a set of values.

Comment: I've tried that, but I get a cyclic dependency. Is there a special way you have to import it to use this.http.get() in a service/component after you've declared the provider like this?

Comment: Please provide more details. What is the exact error message?

Comment: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! (Http -> Http)

Comment: Right, that's actually to be expected. I guess it would be better to not provide it as `Http` but just `bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, HttpClient])` and then inject it as `contructor(private http:HttpClient)`, otherwise you would need a factory that creates an `Http` instance with `new Http(....)`

Comment: :*(   Ok. Thanks. My worry though is that on a large team, ppl may forget/not-know to use the HttpClient. Was hoping to just avoid that by overriding Http in the bootstrap.

Comment: I see. I updated my answer. Not tested but I think it should work.

Comment: No dice. I get `No provider for ConnectionBackend! (Http -> ConnectionBackend)`.

Comment: Can you please try to replace `ConnectionBackend` with `XHRBackend` (in `deps`)?

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much Gunter! I also found an article right as we arrived here that describes this strategy. Link added to OP.